# Change date format in single column

Tags: bash

I have a file with a 1000 lines. The first column has a date in then European standard (DD.MM.YYYY). There are about 20 other columns with different data. The columns are separated by a semicolon. Here's a simplified example.

```
10.12.2020;name;address
18.12.2020;name2;address2
21.12.2020;name3;address3
```

What I want to do is to change the date format in the first column to YYYY.MM.DD

In this case the final line should read

```
2020.12.10;name;address
2020.12.18;name2;address2
2020.12.21;name3;address3
```

I tried to do it with a combination of awk and sed

```
awk -F';' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} NR != 0 { sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\).\([0-9]\{2\}\).\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\3.\2.\1/g'; print; }'
```

which results in errors. There is probably a better way to do it with gsub but I wasn't able to understand the syntax.

Can anyone help me achieve this result? Could be with sed, gsub or any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to combine `sed` and `awk`. Either is sufficient:

```
sed -E 's/^(..)\.(..)\.(....);/\3.\2.\1;/'
```

or

```
awk -F\; -v OFS=\; '{split($1,a,"."); $1=a[3] "." a[2] "." a[1]; print}'
```

Comment: Awesome, I used your second suggestion. Thank you.